# Android Socket: получение сообщений от сервера

Tags: android, сокет

Написал код клиента к серверу. Всё подключается и сообщения от клиента к серверу доходят исправно. Но не могу реализовать отправку сообщений с сервера к клиенту. Точнее сказать сервер данные отправляет, а вот клиент на Андроиде их не читает, т.к. не могу реализовать процесс слушания сокета на Андроиде. Прошу помощи, что и как написать.

Вот тот код который у меня есть

```
public class MessengerActivityChat extends Activity {
private Socket socket;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 2365;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    final ArrayList<String> chat = new ArrayList<String>();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chat);

    try {
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         String IP = intent.getStringExtra("IP");
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(IP);

        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    chat.add(0, editText.getText().toString());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    editText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void onClick3(View view) {
try {
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String str = et.getText().toString();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);
    out.println(str);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Клиент не нужно принуждать слушать, он — клиент, — он и так слушает.

Там, где объявлется `PrintWriter out` нужно добавить вот что:

```
DataInputStream in;

try
    {
    in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }
catch (IOException e)    /* ... */
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Разумеется, вместо `DataInputStream` можно подобрать что-нибудь поудобнее. [Вот неплохой пример](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/).

Comment: Ничего не получается, я переписал код с примера, который по ссылке, всё вроде запускается но вот чтения не происходит всё равно( даже не знаю уже что делать(

Comment: Что делать — убедиться, что сервер действительно что-то отправляет. Может, сервер только буферизирует?

Для уточнения скажу, что по-моему, код из примера у меня взлетел сразу, правда сервер у меня был не на андроиде, а Win32 C++ Indy TCP Server. Клиент я под андроид делал, просто скопировал код примера — заработало, по-моему, без вмешательств в код клиента, так что, он рабочий.